# How to click on the `OK` button on the confirmation window using selenium-webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a file deletion script using `selenium-webdriver`from the webpage. Now when I clicked on the `RED` cross button as in the below image,getting another confirmation window on the page.

Any idea how to click on the `OK` button?

[image: How to click on OK button]

Comment: From the picture, it does not look like a real popup (ie might just be a div tag with button elements). It would be useful to see the html of the popup.

Comment: @JustinKo when I clicked on the `red cross` over there that window comes up as an confirmation,before delete that file. Now my question is how to click on the `OK` button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code finally works to handle the picture mentioned `modal` window:

```
driver.switch_to.alert.accept
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with below logic?

```
Alert alert = driver.switch_to.alert
alert.accept
```

Comment: getting the error as `D:\Rubyscript\My ruby learning days\Scripts>W9_File_delete.rb
D:/Rubyscript/My ruby learning days/Scripts/W9_File_delete.rb:117:in `<main>': u
ndefined method `Alert' for main:Object (NoMethodError)`

Comment: I think you need to import org.openqa.selenium.Alert class.